# Biopython not able to work in UNIX Ubuntu or Mac OS

Tags: python, ubuntu, biopython

I am currently struggling to be able to import the Bio module in a python script which is in a different directory.

The error I keep receiving is as follow:

```
from Bio import SeqIO

ImportError: No module named 'Bio'
```

I have tried reinstalling Biopython, rebuilding it and also changing the paths (as all recommended on Stackoverflow, but still I get this error message.

I built Biopython according to the pypi.python.org site instructions:

```
python setup.py build
python setup.py test
sudo python setup.py install
```

I am still quite new to how Python and BioPython works. Is there a possible solution to this?

Comment: Try `import site; site.getsitepackages()` in python consolle. This will show you the site-package directory that contains all the modules. Put the Bio module directory under the site-package directory.

Comment: Even better, use this command to install it: `pip install biopython`. This will automatically put the module in the default python site-package.

Comment: If you are new to Python, please use Python 3 instead of Python 2 - i.e., run `python3` on the command line instead of `python`.

Comment: Thank you Terence and Matt.

Comment: I tried installing with pip but it still gives the same issue. I also tried it with python3. I'm running the test again to see if I can find the problem.

Comment: Try the distribution package: sudo apt-get install python-biopython

Comment: Did you tried to import the full Bio module: `import Bio`. If the installation with pip was successful then I cannot see why python cannot find the module. Wait, on OSX the default is python2.7 if you installed python 3 then you also have pip3.X, to install modules for python3.X use pip3.X.

Comment: BTW You can use @name syntax anywhere in your comment to reply to a specific user (so that the user will be notified of your reply, see this [post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work) on comments.

Comment: @terencehill I'm reading "UNIX Ubuntu" in the title.

Comment: @xbello yeah! My apology.  Sometimes I'm so dumb that I can't belive it

Comment: Any success so far?

Answer (score 0):

**What worked for me was:**

First uninstall all trace of biopython

In the terminal:

- pip uninstall biopython
- pip3 uninstall biopython
- pip3.X uninstall biopython

Note: If you have python3.7 is pip3.7, python3.7.6 will still be pip3.7

Then see which python do you use, in the terminal:

- which python
- which python3

Then, the main process is:

1. **dowload manually** biopython-1.74.tar.gz 16Mb – Source Tarball from https://biopython.org/wiki/Download
2. decompress/unzip/tar biopython-1.74.tar.gz
3. in the terminal change directory to biopython-1.74 and:

   - python setup.py build
   - python setup.py test
   - sudo python setup.py install

or

- python3 setup.py build
- python3 setup.py test
- sudo ython3 setup.py install

or

- python3.X setup.py build
- python3.X setup.py test
- sudo python3.X setup.py install

DONE! https://pypi.org/project/biopython/